# Simply way to set default index of an array to be all unless specified

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a numpy array (the following will be a trivial example of what I am trying to achieve)

```
test = np.array([[0,1,2][3,4,5]])
```

and I want the user to be able to specify a index that they want to view

```
ind = 4
```

but I want this to be in a function

```
def view(array, index):
    print array[index]
```

If the user doesn't input an index, I want it to print the entire array.

```
test[:]
```

Is there a way to do this simply? I know you could do it with an if statement, but when I need to do this for 10 different arrays, the code become clunky when I figured there had to be a simpler way to do it.

So right now my method would consist of

```
def view(array, index=False):
    if index:
         print array[index]
    else:
         print array[:]
```

I am asking if there is a more efficient or more pythonic way of achieving this.

Comment: Your current implementation also has a bug because `0` evaluates to `False`. `view(test, 0)` will `print` the whole array instead of the first element.

Comment: Good point, thats what I get for constructing a fake example so quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the default value for the `index` parameter a `slice` object using the [built-in `slice` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice):

```
>>> def view(array, index=slice(None)):
    print array[index]


>>> view(test)
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]]
>>> view(test, 1)
[3 4 5]
```